# Oracle trigger to increment value in another table after inserted in other

Tags: oracle, triggers, sqlplus, procedure

How to create trigger or procedure to add incrementally +1 in column VALUE in TABLE1 every single time when something is inserted in TABLE2 ?

Lets say that we start from VALUE.TABLE1 = 1 and I insert record in TABLE2. After that I should see 2 in VALUE column in TABLE1.
Then someone else is inserting record in TABLE2 and that procedure/trigger should add yet again +1 in VALUE and now it should be 3
etc.

DB is Oracle 11

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **table** `table1` and don't use a **trigger**.

Use a **view** instead:

```
create or replace view v_table1 as
  select count(*) + 1 as value
  from table2;
```

Comment: The OP appears to only be counting insertions; this will count insertions and subtract for deletions and may not give the desired result.

Comment: Right; I understood the problem as "I want to know how many rows are right now in table2". Maybe I was wrong, and maybe not. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER table2_trg
AFTER INSERT 
ON table2
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE table1 set value = value + 1;
END;
```

Or

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE2_trg
FOR INSERT 
ON TABLE2
COMPOUND TRIGGER 
 
cnt PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  
AFTER EACH ROW IS 
BEGIN 
  cnt := cnt + 1;
END AFTER EACH ROW ;
  
AFTER STATEMENT IS 
BEGIN 
   UPDATE table1 SET value = value + cnt;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
```

I am not sure it is better or not and how it will work when some rows in table2 are dropped due to exceptions at the time of insertion.

It's better to use view if don't bother about deleted rows in table2.